# Disable submit button and submit form via isset

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

How to disable submit button and submit the form with isset?

```
<script>
     function Check()
     {
          some codes for validation.
         if(ok)
         {
              return true;
         }
         else
         {
              return false;
         }
     }
</script>

<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return Check()" >
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="Submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>


<?php 
      if(isset($_POST['Submit']) == "Submit")
      { 
         echo "test"; 
      } 
?>
```

When I disabled the submit button, the `isset` submit did not work.

Comment: of course, if it's disabled how can it be set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixed up here, you cannot submit the form with `isset`, the php code only runs when the page loads and not after it loads.

You can use jquery to submit your form if you want another way other than the submit button :

`$("#formId").submit();` in your script tag after loading the jquery library.

The `isset` can check if the submit button is sent through POST when the form is submitted, since you have an empty action, the form will submit to the same page it exists within.

You shall make sure to **re-enable** the submit button if your javascript validation fails in order to allow the user to fix his form input and submit again (this really depends on your code behavior but it is good practice).

Answer (score 0):

php can't interact with html but you can use php to set various html attributes

```
<?php 
$disable = "";
if(isset($_POST['Submit']) == "Submit"){ 
 $disable = "disable=disable";
} 
?>
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return Check()" >
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="Submit" value="Submit" <?php echo $disable;?>/>
</form>
```